# How can I change y axis label "density" to bold on a histogram?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
par(font=2)
hist(x, freq=F, cex.lab=1.8, cex.axis=1.6, font=2,
     col=rgb(1, 0.75, 0.3,1),
     breaks=7, ylab="Density",
     xlim=c(0,35), ylim=c(0,.6), 
     main="")
```

And the y-axis label density just came as default. I want to make that word bold, what command could I use? font=2 did not seem to work and par(font=2) before calling the histogram did not seem to work either.

!(http://s30.postimg.org/6oo5xbf9d/for_SO.png)

Comment: use `font.lab = 2` instead of `font = 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

#### Option 1

Use an expression for the `ylab`, as in

```
ylab = expression(bold(Density))
```

E.g.

```
hist(faithful$waiting, ylab = expression(bold(Density)))
```

#### Option 2

Draw the label separately and fiddle with the `font.lab` parameter, as in

```
hist(faithful$waiting, ylab = "")
title(ylab = "Density", font.lab = 2)
```

The reason I draw the `ylab` in a separate call is that if one did

```
hist(faithful$waiting, ylab = "Density", font.lab = 2)
```

both the x-axis and y-axis labels will be in bold font and you didn't indicate that you wanted this.